# How to read only numbers in file .txt?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I need to read only numbers from a file. The file contains:

```
0
#####################
#    |    |    |    #
#    |    |    |   2#
#    |    |   2|    #
#    |    |    |    #
#####################
```

I only want to read the first 0 that will be the score and the other two numbers. Whitespaces I want to save them as 0. I want to save the score into an int and the rest into a vector.

So the vector should contain:

```
score = 0
0000000200200000
```

My code is the next, but it doesn't work:

```
string line;
vector<int> v;
int sscore = 0, count = 0;
ifstream in ("save_game.txt");
vector<vector<Tile> > vt;

if (in.is_open()) {

    while (getline (in, line)) {
        if (line.size() == 1)
            sscore = str2int(line);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int) line.size(); i++) {
                string l = line.substr(i, 1);
                char c = l[0];
                if (l[0] == '#' || l[0] == '|') {count = 0;}
                else {
                    if (c != ' ') {
                        count = 0;
                        int ss = str2int(l);
                        v.push_back(ss);
                    }
                    else {
                        count++;
                        if (count == 3)
                            v.push_back(0); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    in.close();
}
```

And here is the str2int function

```
int str2int(string s){
    istringstream reader(s);
    unsigned int val = 0;
    reader >> val;
    return val;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your example, number of zeros doesn't match number of whitespaces. And did you try anything. If yes, show us.

Comment: It's a 4x4 grid, so I need a vector of size 16, I have two 2, so I need fourteen 0. I'm going to edit to add my code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So, for 3 whitespaces you push 1 `0` to the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the other input and save what is a digit , check what i did it worked for the same text file you posted, in the end the vector must have 0 2 2 as values.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnrWK.png)

I forgot to make 0 all the other characters but that isn't an issue now just replace continue; statement in the screen shot with nums.push_back(0);

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use only simple stream extraction operations here (actually, maybe `boost::regex_split`), no `std::string` parsing.

- Read the first `0` with `operator>>`, then `std::ignore` to remove the trailing newline character, or `std::getline` and check if no extra (non-whitespace) characters are present
- `std::ignore` or `std::getline` and validate the `####` lines.
- Use `operator>>` with a `char` and validate that it is `#`.
- In a loop, try `operator>>` with `int` defaulted to `0`, if it fails, `in.clear()` and use `operator>>` with a `char` to read what doesn't seem to be a number, but either `|` or `#`. Continue the loop according to that.
- Handle the rest of the line after the second `#` similarly to the 1st bullet point

---

Always check if every extraction operation succeeded.